# Why use this keyword in object constructor Function Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var x = new y ('hello');

function y (mes){
    this.mes = mes;

    //x.mes = mes;
    //Why using object name will not work, with this it will work. 
    //please read the description what i am trying to ask.
}
```

**Explanation of the problem**

I am learning Javascript, From MDN,

I am on the topic working with Object. link is 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

I am on the topic **Using Object Constructor Function**

In here they are basically saying if you want to create similar object use this object constructor function.

First I notice they are using keyword `this` in the function code. I was kinda confuse, than I google it why they are using `this` keyword instead of simply using variable.

Than it kinda make sense, as what I understood by my google search is this, that `this` keyword is refer to the object means object which I am initiating with the keyword `new`,

so I thought I should be able to use object name directly instead of using the `this`.

I will just initiate the object before the function, and than  I should be able to use the object name, and it did not work.

**(I am aware if I do this, it actually defeat the purpose of using Object Constructor Function, but that not the point is, the point is do I understand what this means in this context or why it did not work.)**

Comment: Also, you forgot to define "it doesn't work". What does it _mean_ exactly?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i know you have two many point but please read the question, second javasscript put the function at the top with the declration, and third i know i said it in the bold read the last lines which i typed in the bold

Comment: There's also this temporal disconnect. `x` is not fully defined/initialized until after `y` returns, but you're trying to access it while `y` still runs.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i got your last point, but what i am confuse about it should behave same with this key word, but it does not, so i am thinking i got some thing wrong about the this keyword, thanks for the last comment. It give me some explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short

Using `var` you are declaring local variable in constructor function, It will not accessible outside the constructor function

`this` is not a variable It is a property of the object, `this` will survive as long as the object survive

In below example we can not access `a` in call function but by using `this` we can access `b`

Es6 Class

let suppose you declare Test class

```
class Test{
  constructor(){
    var a = "hello";
    this.b = "world";
   }
  call(){
     console.log(t.b);
     console.log(t.a);
  }
}


var t = new Test();

console.log(t.b); //will print "world"

console.log(t.a); //will print "undefined"
```

same concept with normal function

```
function Test() {
    var a = "hello";
    this.b = "world";
}
```

Comment: Nishant i think i got the answer from you, but i am not able to understand, can you try to explain the first two lines which you wrote in your answer, thanks. In short Please can you explain the first lines, becuase if i do understand those lines i will be able to get it, thanks